# Write data into Google Spreadsheet using Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

AM trying to Insert data's into Google Spreadsheet . With the Help of `Tabletop`(GitHub code ) , I can able to Read the data's from the Sheet likewise i need to Write the Data's into that . How can i achieve this ?  What are all the ways to write the data's into Google spread sheet . Here is my **Spread sheet Read Code** ,

```
$scope.samm=function() {

    $log.log("inside logProduction")

       Tabletop.init( { key: 'http://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?hl=en_US&hl=en_US&key=1dU_DbFxsuzdJFjWKEyyYiuJiAkZaZRQzy2O-2svIlNg',
                        callback: showInfo,
                        simpleSheet: true } )
      };


     function showInfo(data, tabletop) {
       alert("Successfully processed!")
       console.log(data);
     };
```

Comment: identical to your other question http://stackoverflow.com/q/39065119/2213940

Answer (score 4):

If you want to write data to Google Spreadsheet in java or javascript then you can use the [Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/guides/concepts)

Comment: Can i have a sample  Working code sample Kishan ? Like jsfidle,plunker or something ..Am newbie so that i can i get some more clarification

Comment: Sample code for both Java and JavaScript is also provided on the link that I have shared...

Comment: There is a Problem while am Running that code  , `Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('file://') does not match the recipient window's origin ('null').`